# Command binding not working - MVVM Light RelayCommand and XAML issues

Tags: c#, xaml, command, mvvm-light

I have a listbox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="TestCasesList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TestCases}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails, ElementName=TestCasesList}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Failures}">
...
```

I have a view model added to my DataContext:

```
<Window x:Class="blah.UI.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
    Name="Window">
```

I have a view model RelayCommand:

```
    ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails = new RelayCommand<List<Failure>>( (param) => Execute_ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails(param) );


    public RelayCommand<List<Failure>> ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void Execute_ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails( List<Failure> failures )
    {
        Failures = new ObservableCollection<Failure>(failures);
    }
```

The button is not firing my command, any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the command binding as I show below:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand_DisplayFailureDetails}" ...>
```

This way you can get the `DataContext` property of your window which was set with an instance of your ViewModel.